# tableView Cell goes behind the admob banner ad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, admob, banner

I have created a tableViewController and add an admob banner ad to the bottom of the tableViewController using swift. Everything works fine but when scroll the tableView, tableViewCell goes behind the banner ad. And the bottom most cell cannot be tapped as it goes behind the banner. What can i do? Please help.

Comment: Add constraint to "bottom of your tableview to top of adMob banner".

Answer (score 0):

use autolayout? 
try add NSAutoLauout constraint @"V:|[tableView][adView]|"

objc code example

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableView][adView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tableView, adView)]];